# Installing Blocks on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, theano

I'm trying to [install Blocks](http://blocks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setup.html) on my Linux machine and I have some troubles. How can I fix this? I'm doing the following steps:

1. Installing [Anaconda for python2](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix).
2. Theano depends on numpy 1.10.1 version. If at this step I will run `import theano` in python shell then it will work perfectly.
3. Okay, it's time for Blocks. I'm installing stable version using `pip install --user git+git://github.com/mila-udem/blocks.git \
   -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mila-udem/blocks/master/requirements.txt`
4. After this step if I import theano it gives the following: `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9`.
5. I looked at requirements.txt and see that Blocks depends on numpy 1.9.3.
6. I uninstalled Theano, Blocks, downgraded numpy using `conda install numpy=1.9.3`, then just run again `pip install --user git+git://github.com/mila-udem/blocks.git \
   -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mila-udem/blocks/master/requirements.txt` and still while importing theano it gives me `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: This could be a problem with the Anaconda distribution. You could try updating all of Anaconda via `conda update conda` and `conda update --all`. You could also try changing Blocks requirements.txt to refer to numpy 1.10.1 since it's likely that Blocks won't care about the changes from 1.9 to 1.10.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw, thank you! That works, but now I have another trouble: I'm trying to reproduce [Blocks tutorial][1] and everything is failing at this step: `mnist = MNIST(("train",))`. It outputs `fuel.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Configuration not set and no default provided: data_path.`

[1]: http://blocks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: That appears unrelated. I suggest creating a new question, with all the detail.

Comment: This is unrelated. You have to set this path to enable fuel. See fuel installation docs.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the Anaconda distribution. You could try updating all of Anaconda via `conda update conda` and `conda update --all`. You could also try changing Blocks requirements.txt to refer to numpy 1.10.1 since it's likely that Blocks won't care about the changes from 1.9 to 1.10.
                    – Daniel Renshaw